# KNIME does not create TEMP table

Tags: postgresql, knime

I have tried to create TEMP table using "Database SQL Executor" node using expression:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS
SELECT type_id, created_at
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = (SELECT id
FROM t2
WHERE id = t1.id
AND event_date <= created_at
ORDER BY event_date DESC
LIMIT 1);
```

Unfortunately despite the fact there is neither no mistake in pure syntax (above code works when run from PSQL console) nor error after node execution, table does not exist in database.

**EDIT :** Thanks to @SABER-FICTIONALCHARACTER

[image]

Comment: try using commit after creating table. fyi: you cant see temp table in database cause they were created in another schema

Comment: @SABER-FICTIONALCHARACTER U were right! No need to commit as I created two test-tables with and w/o the COMMIT statement and both appeared in "Database reader" node under "TEMPORARY TABLE". Many thanks!